# Complex analysis: find and sketch the image of the line $y=\sinh^{−1}(2)$ under the mapping $w=\sin(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

My question is

> Find and sketch the image of the line $y=\sinh^{−1}(2)$ under the mapping $w=\sin(z)$.
>
> Write down the image curve as one equation in $u$ and $v$ where $w=u+iv$ for $u,v\in\mathbb{R}$.

I'm not sure how to go about this when there's trigonometry involved. I know I need $\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)$, but what happens after that?

Comment: Well, for starters, don't you know the value of $\sinh(y)$ for all the points on the given line?

Comment: 2? is there a rule that will help me narrow down the shape it should be? should i test points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, from $y=\sinh^{-1}(2)$, we know that $\sinh(y)=2$ for all points on this line. Then from the identity $\cosh^2(y)-\sinh^2(y)=1$, we can find that $\cosh(y)=\sqrt{5}$ (because $\cosh$ of a real number is always positive). Now we can put these values into what you already know:
$$\sin(x+iy)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)=\sqrt{5}\sin(x)+2i\cos(x)=u+iv,$$
where
$$u=\sqrt{5}\sin(x), \quad v=2\cos(x), \quad x\in\mathbb{R}.$$
These are the parametric equations of the ellipse $\displaystyle \frac{u^2}{5}+\frac{v^2}{4}=1$.

Comment: Oh i forgot about the hyperbolic identity cosh2(y)−sinh2(y)=1. thank you :)